# What kind of nut is this?

Tags: nuts

Nuts are not very popular in my region, this is the first time I have this kind of nut, can you let me know what its name is?

Thank you.
[image]

Comment: Can you say something about the size? I imagined them walnut sized, but the one answer which suggests chickpeas could be right shapewise, if they are much smaller.

Comment: around the size of a m&m chocolate, ~1cm in diameter or less.

Comment: Could be corn nut.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like roasted chickpeas which are actually a legume (related to peas & beans), but you can toast them up and eat like nuts (like you would peanuts/groundnuts which are also legumes).